# Should I send an email back after getting rejected for a Master Project?

Tags: graduate-admissions

Planning to do a Master degree in Canada but my professor is not planning to take in any students for the upcoming year. Should I send an email back or just leave it as it is? If I should send one back, what is the proper way of writing one?

Comment: "An email back" - what for? To thank him, apologize, ask for something, provide a pizza recipe?

Comment: Just want to thank him for his time to read my application that's all. Is it a bit too much? Been getting two-sided answer so just want to make sure what is the right thing to do in these kind of situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never lose by being polite - especially to people who can possibly help you in the future. I would suggest sending an email, or even postal mail - a bit more formal.

The email/note should be short. Thanks for your consideration of my application. I appreciate your help and hope to be able to work with you in the future.

If you need a project from another professor, you could also ask him/her for any advice or recommendations they might have.

Don't burn your bridges. Don't let them fall into disrepair. Keep them tidy and well swept.

Comment: These professors are busy. If they said that they are not taking in anybody, it's likely that they have other things on their mind. Don't send a mail back unless you are sure that you do not bother them. Assume that 50 students think the same way as you do - these means 50 extra mails to answer.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs, I disagree, of course. Send the email but don't expect a reply. You can even give a ps that no reply is needed if you think that there is a problem of scale. In particular, don't ask questions in the mail that seem to require an answer.

Comment: Of course, you are entitled to disagree. But I suggest you give a reason. If you create extra work for the prof, what is the purpose of it? Today,  with the amount of communication going on, politeness expresses itself more by not creating extra work for someone than pushing one's business card in their hands. It is an entirely different thing, of course, if the student has done an internship/practical/project that highlights that they will be an interesting person to consider in the future. But just "self-name-dropping" has little value.

Comment: Thank you for both of your advice. From the looks of it, I guess I will just leave it as it is.